# Change the src for all images with a specific class

Tags: jquery, html

In my code I have some `<div class="sign">` and there are `<img class="sign" alt="hi"  src="img.jpg">`.

I want to change all the src of images with class="sign".

I think I should do something like:

```
$("img.sign").each(function () {
    src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Pi_SzgTqSg8/TecelklSUVI/AAAAAAAAAKk/Rpcdzw4jYOY/s1600/Chrome.png";
});
```

But I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

Comment: don't you forget a space `$("img .sign")` ?

Comment: _src of null_? That isn't your actual code, right? You are only declaring a global variable that doesn't throw such error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I want to change all the src of images with `class="sign"`".

No need for a loop like the other answers suggest; do it in one line:

```
$('img.sign').attr('src', 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Pi_SzgTqSg8/TecelklSUVI/AAAAAAAAAKk/Rpcdzw4jYOY/s1600/Chrome.png');
```

**Edit:** In reply to your comments, if you wanted to change the `alt` of all `img.sign`'s to `222` as well:

```
$('img.sign').attr({
    src: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Pi_SzgTqSg8/TecelklSUVI/AAAAAAAAAKk/Rpcdzw4jYOY/s1600‌​/Chrome.png',
    alt: '222' 
});
```

[**jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvYYr/)

Comment: thank you. the src was changed. why the alt isn't changed? $(this).attr('alt', '222');

Comment: @AlonShmiel To change the alt of all the images with the class sign to 222, use $('img.sign').attr('alt','222');

Comment: @Zenith it doesn't work. I put it: $('img.sign').attr('alt','222'); $("img.sign").each(function () {
                                $(this).attr('src', 'time.png');
                            });

Comment: @AlonShmiel No need for the each loop as I mentioned. Please check my update :)

Comment: @Zenith I'm sorry but the `alt` doesn't work :/ I saw your jsFiddle.. can you fix this problem please? thank you very much!

Comment: @AlonShmiel There is no problem. It works perfectly. If you saw my jsFiddle and looked at the console.log then you would see.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
$(this).attr('src','your path');
```

When you want to set an attribute value use .attr()

and you can directly set with out any loop .if you use class as selector that will apply to all the matched elements.

[**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("img.sign").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src","http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Pi_SzgTqSg8/TecelklSUVI/AAAAAAAAAKk/Rpcdzw4jYOY/s1600/Chrome.png");
});
```